# Calling Javascript Closure Functions Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, closures

[Marked as a duplicate but would argue it is not; it addresses the same common example but the users posed different questions regarding it.]

I have been reading up on javascript closures but I am puzzled by two examples I found. The link below is from one of the stackoverflow articles I read and another snippet of code is from a javascript tutorial site.

Stackoverflow: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (Specifically Example 4).

Tutorial example:

```html
    <p>Counting with a local variable.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>
    <p id="demo">0</p>

    <script>
    var add = (function () {
        var counter = 0;
        return function () {return counter += 1;}
    })();

    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
    }
    </script>
```

In the code snippet above, a self invoking function is called once declaring and setting `counter=0`. Then pressing the button triggers the `add()` function and the counter increments, i.e `1 then 2 then 3..`.

My question is why? I know that the return function has access to the parent scope `counter` but if the `add()` function gets called again multiple times, should `counter` not get reset multiple times back to `0` every time it is called? I believe the 'lexical environment' of each call is the same.

In Example 4 of the linked stackoverflow discussion, calling the function again reinitialized the variables as I would expect. Does this have something to do with `var` being used to declare the function?

Tried also looking at the Mozilla documentation but it doesn't cover this type of scenario:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: `add` is just called once. The anonymous function is called multiple times.

Comment: `add` variable stores a result of calling _outer_ anonymous function (that does declare `var counter`). That outer function is called just once. Resulting function doesn't have `counter` declared inside it - it uses it from outside scope.

Comment: but when a button is pressed, isn't `add()` called each time?

Comment: You're correct, `add` is called multiple times.

Comment: @raina77ow i didn't know this; I thought `add` stores the entire contents of the function, and not just the `return ...` portion?

Comment: `add` is a variable that references this anonymous function: `function () {return counter += 1;}`.

Comment: The other anonymous function was called once at the start as an IIFE and its return value was assigned to `add`.